# Javascript Can't resolve all parameters for

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I am using Ionic2 to implement an app that uses SQLite.

I am getting the following error, and if anyone can help, I would appreciate it. I am not actually sure where to look.

> ```
> EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppRoot class AppRoot_Host - inline template:0:0 app.bundle.js:44905
> EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppRoot class AppRoot_Host - inline template:0:0 app.bundle.js:44896
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for ChatsStorageService: (?). app.bundle.js:44896
> ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: app.bundle.js:44896
> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ChatsStorageService: (?).
>     at new BaseException (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:25523:24)
>     at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:38037:20)
>     at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:37918:27)
>     at file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:38072:31
>     at Array.map (native)
>     at Object.Call (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/es6-shim.min.js:10:4652)
>     at Array.map (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/es6-shim.min.js:10:19780)
>     at CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:38060:27)
>     at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:37868:35)
>     at RuntimeCompiler._getCompiledHostTemplate (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:36412:52)
> ```

[image]

**chatsStorageService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';
import { Chat, Message } from 'api/models';
import { Messages } from 'api/collections';
import { SqlDatabase } from './SqlDatabase';
import { isBrowser } from './platform';
import { SqlResultSet } from './SqlResultSet';

@Injectable()
export class ChatsStorageService {

    private database = null;
    private databaseName: string = 'data.db.thewhozoo';
    public chats: Array<Chat> = new Array<Chat>();
    public messages: Array<Message> = new Array<Message>();


    private dbPromise: Promise<SqlDatabase>;

    constructor(private _db: any) {
    }

    public createDatabase(): void {
        const createChatsTable: string = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chats (_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, memberIds TEXT, title TEXT, subTitle TEXT, picture TEXT, lastMessageId TEXT, lastMessageCreatedAt DATE)";
        const createMessagesTable: string = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, chatId TEXT, senderId TEXT, ownership TEXT, content TEXT, createdAt DATE, changeDate BOOLEAN, readByReceiver BOOLEAN)";
        this.dbPromise = SqlDatabase.open(this.databaseName, [createChatsTable, createMessagesTable]);
        this.dbPromise.then((data) => {
            console.log('database ' + this.databaseName + ' created');
        });
    }

    public refreshChats(): Promise<any> {
        const statement: string = "SELECT * FROM chats";
        return this.dbPromise
            .then((db) => db.execute(statement))
            .then((resultSet) => {
                this.chats = [];
                if (resultSet.rows.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < resultSet.rows.length; i++) {
                        this.populateChat(resultSet.rows.item(i));
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    private populateChat(chatItem: any): Promise<any> {
        const statement: string = "SELECT * FROM messages where _id = ?";
        const params: string[] = [chatItem.lastMessageId];
        let messages: Array<Message> = new Array<Message>();
        return this.dbPromise
            .then((db) => db.execute(statement, params))
            .then((messageData) => {
                this.chats = [];
                if (messageData.rows.length > 0) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < messageData.rows.length; j++) {
                        if (messageData.rows.item(j)) {
                            let messageValue: Message = { _id: messageData.rows.item(j)._id, chatId: messageData.rows.item(j).chatId, senderId: messageData.rows.item(j).senderId, ownership: messageData.rows.item(j).ownership, content: messageData.rows.item(j).content, createdAt: messageData.rows.item(j).createdAt, changeDate: messageData.rows.item(j).changeDate, readByReceiver: messageData.rows.item(j).readByReceiver };
                            messages.push(messageValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
                let chatValue: Chat = {
                    _id: chatItem._id, memberIds: chatItem.memberIds, title: chatItem.title, subTitle: chatItem.subTitle,
                    picture: chatItem.picture, lastMessage: messages[0], lastMessageCreatedAt: chatItem.lastMessageCreatedAt
                };
                if (this.chats.indexOf(chatValue) === -1) {
                    this.chats.push(chatValue);
                }
            });
    }

    public refreshMessages(): Promise<any> {
        const statement: string = "SELECT * FROM messages";
        return this.dbPromise
            .then((db) => db.execute(statement))
            .then((resultSet) => {
                this.messages = [];
                if (resultSet.rows.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < resultSet.rows.length; i++) {
                        if (resultSet.rows.item(i)) {
                            this.messages.push({ _id: resultSet.rows.item(i)._id, chatId: resultSet.rows.item(i).chatId, senderId: resultSet.rows.item(i).senderId, ownership: resultSet.rows.item(i).ownership, content: resultSet.rows.item(i).content, createdAt: resultSet.rows.item(i).createdAt, changeDate: resultSet.rows.item(i).changeDate, readByReceiver: resultSet.rows.item(i).readByReceiver });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    public addChat(chat: Chat): Promise<any> {
        if (window.cordova) {
            if (this.chats.indexOf(chat) < 0) {
                const statement: string = "INSERT INTO chats (_id, memberIds, title, subTitle, picture, lastMessageId, lastMessageCreatedAt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                const params: any[] = [chat._id, chat.memberIds, chat.title, chat.subTitle, chat.picture, chat.lastMessage._id, chat.lastMessageCreatedAt];
                this.chats.push(chat);
                return this.dbPromise
                    .then((db) => db.execute(statement, params))
                    .then((resultSet) => {
                        console.log('added chat: ', resultSet);
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    public updateChat(chat: Chat): Promise<any> {
        if (window.cordova) {
            let idx: number = this.contains(this.chats, chat);
            if (idx >= 0) {
                this.chats[idx] = chat;
                const statement: string = "UPDATE chats SET memberIds = ?, title = ?, subTitle = ?, picture = ?, lastMessageId = ?, lastMessageCreatedAt = ? WHERE _id = ?"
                const params: any[] = [chat.memberIds, chat.title, chat.subTitle, chat.picture, chat.lastMessage._id, chat.lastMessageCreatedAt, chat._id];
                return this.dbPromise
                    .then((db) => db.execute(statement, params))
                    .then((resultSet) => {
                        console.log('updated chat: ', resultSet);
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    public updateMessage(message: Message): Promise<any> {
        if (window.cordova) {
            let idx: number = this.contains(this.messages, message);
            if (idx >= 0) {
                this.messages[idx] = message;
                const statement: string = "UPDATE messages SET readByReceiver = ? WHERE _id = ?";
                const params: any[] = [message.readByReceiver, message._id];
                return this.dbPromise
                    .then((db) => db.execute(statement, params))
                    .then((resultSet) => {
                        console.log('updated message: ', resultSet);
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    private contains(arr: Array<any>, obje: any): number {
        for (let i: number = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i]._id === obje._id) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public removeChat(chat: Chat): Promise<any> {
        if (window.cordova) {
            let idx: number = this.chats.indexOf(chat);
            if (idx >= 0) {
                const selectStatement: string = "SELECT * FROM chats where _id = ?";
                const selectParams: string[] = [chat._id];
                const deleteStatement: string = "DELETE FROM chats where _id = ?";
                const deleteParams: string[] = [chat._id];
                for (let i: number = 0; i < this.messages.length; i++) {
                    if (this.messages[i].chatId === chat._id) {
                        this.removeMessage(this.messages[i]);
                    }
                }
                this.chats.splice(idx, 1);
                return this.dbPromise
                    .then((db) => db.execute(selectStatement, selectParams))
                    .then((resultSet) => {
                        if (resultSet && resultSet.rows.length > 0) {
                            return this.dbPromise
                                .then((db) => db.execute(deleteStatement, deleteParams))
                                .then((resultSet) => {
                                    console.log('chat deleted: ', resultSet);
                                });
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    public addMessage(chat: Chat, message: Message): Promise<Message> {
        let promise: Promise<Message> = new Promise<Message>(resolve => {
            if (window.cordova) {
                const statement: string = "SELECT * FROM chats where _id = ?";
                const params: string[] = [chat._id];
                return this.dbPromise
                    .then((db) => db.execute(statement, params))
                    .then((resultSet) => {
                        if (!resultSet || resultSet.rows.length === 0) {
                            this.addChat(chat);
                        }
                        if (this.messages.indexOf(message) < 0) {
                            this.addTheMessage(message);
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
        return promise;
    }

    private addTheMessage(message: Message): Promise<any> {
        const selectStatement: string = "SELECT * FROM messages where _id = ?";
        const selectParams: string[] = [message._id];
        const insertStatement: string = "INSERT INTO messages (_id, chatId, senderId, ownership, content, createdAt, changeDate, readByReceiver) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        const insterParams: any[] = [message._id, message.chatId, message.senderId, message.ownership, message.content, message.createdAt, message.changeDate, message.readByReceiver];
        return this.dbPromise
            .then((db) => db.execute(selectStatement, selectParams))
            .then((resultSet) => {
                if (!resultSet || resultSet.rows.length === 0) {
                    return this.dbPromise
                        .then((db) => db.execute(insertStatement, insterParams))
                        .then((resultSet) => {
                            if (!resultSet || resultSet.rows.length === 0) {
                                let length: number = this.messages.push(message);
                                console.log('message inserted: ' + length, message);
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
    }

    public removeMessage(message: Message): Promise<any> {
        if (window.cordova) {
            let idx: number = this.messages.indexOf(message);
            if (idx >= 0) {
                const selectStatement: string = "SELECT * FROM messages where _id = ?";
                const selectParams: string[] = [message._id];
                const deleteStatement: string = "DELETE FROM messages where _id = ?";
                const deleteParams: string[] = [message._id];
                this.messages.splice(idx, 1);
                return this.dbPromise
                    .then((db) => db.execute(selectStatement, selectParams))
                    .then((resultSet) => {
                        if (resultSet && resultSet.rows.length > 0) {
                            return this.dbPromise
                                .then((db) => db.execute(deleteStatement, deleteParams))
                                .then((resultSet) => {
                                    console.log('message deleted: ', message);
                                });
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    public findLastMessageForChat(chat: Chat): Promise<Message> {
        let promise: Promise<Message> = new Promise<Message>(resolve => {
            const statement: string = "SELECT * FROM messages where chatId = ? order by createdAt desc";
            const params: string[] = [chat._id];
            return this.dbPromise
                .then((db) => db.execute(statement, params))
                .then((data) => {
                    let message: Message = null;
                    if (data.rows.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                            if (data.rows.item(i)) {
                                message = ({ _id: data.rows.item(i)._id, chatId: data.rows.item(i).chatId, senderId: data.rows.item(i).senderId, ownership: data.rows.item(i).ownership, content: data.rows.item(i).content, createdAt: data.rows.item(i).createdAt, changeDate: data.rows.item(i).changeDate, readByReceiver: data.rows.item(i).readByReceiver });
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    resolve(message);
                });
        });
        return promise;
    }
}
```

**SqlDatabase.ts**

```
import { isBrowser } from './platform';
import { SqlResultSet } from './SqlResultSet';

export class SqlDatabase {

  constructor(private _db: any) { }

  static open(name: string, initStatements: string[] = []): Promise<SqlDatabase> {
    let dbPromise = isBrowser()
      .then(browser => {
        const openDatabase = browser ? openBrowserDatabase : openCordovaDatabase;
        return openDatabase(name);
      });
    if (initStatements.length === 0) {
      return dbPromise;
    }
    let _db: SqlDatabase;
    // execute the first statement and capture the _db
    dbPromise.then(db => {
      _db = db;
      return db.execute(initStatements.shift());
    });
    // execute all the other statements (if any) sequentially
    for (let sql of initStatements) {
      dbPromise.then(() => {
          _db.execute(sql)
        });
    }
    // resolve the _db only after all statements have completed
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dbPromise.then(() => resolve(_db)).catch(reject);
    });
  }

  execute(statement: string, params: any[] = []): Promise<SqlResultSet> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._db.transaction(tx => tx.executeSql(statement, params, (tx, resultSet) => {
        resolve(resultSet);
      }, (tx, error) => {
        reject(error)
      }));
    });
  }

}

declare var sqlitePlugin: any;

function openCordovaDatabase(name: string): Promise<SqlDatabase> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof sqlitePlugin === 'undefined') {
      reject(new Error('[ionix-sqlite] sqlitePlugin global object not found; did you install a Cordova SQLite plugin?'));
    }
    const db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
      name: name,
      location: 'default'
    });
    console.info('[ionix-sqlite] using Cordova sqlitePlugin');
    resolve(new SqlDatabase(db));
  });
}

declare function openDatabase(name: string, version: string, desc: string, size: number): any;

function openBrowserDatabase(name: string): Promise<SqlDatabase> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const db = openDatabase(name, '1.0', name, -1);
      console.info('[ionix-sqlite] using WebSQL');
      resolve(new SqlDatabase(db));
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

**platform.ts**

```
declare var cordova;

export function isBrowser(): Promise<boolean> {
  if (typeof cordova === 'undefined') {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
      resolve(cordova.platformId === 'browser');
    });
  });
}
```

**SqlResultSet.ts**

```
import { SqlResultSetRows } from './SqlResultSetRows';

export interface SqlResultSet {

  insertId: number;
  rowsAffected: number;
  rows: SqlResultSetRows;

}
```

**SqlResultSetRows.ts**

```
export interface SqlResultSetRows {

  length: number;
  item(index: number): any;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had something in the constructor of `chatsStorageService`.ts that needed to be removed.

```
  constructor(private _db: any) { }
```

to

```
constructor() { }
```